# why use role attribute in html5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a web page using html5.

I used source code from bootstrap.

For example: `role="main"`, `role ="navigation"`, `role = "document"` etc.

If I remove these attribute from my code, page didn't any change.

So I want to know: what is the purpose of "role" attribute?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:900,500,600,200,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <title>Layout</title>
      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body role="document">
      <!-- Fixed navbar -->
      <div class="navbar" role="navigation">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <h1><img src="img/logo.png" /></h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
         <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
         <div class="container">
            <div class="banner-div">
               <img src="img/banner.png" class="banner"/>
               <img src="img/issue-no-img.png" class="issue-badge"/>
               <span class="issue">Issue No.<br /><b>376</b></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src="img/left-note-img.png"/>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 align-center">
                  <p><span class="new-radius"> NEW! </span>&nbsp;<span class="new">JUN 07, 2003</span></p>
                  <p><i>Get your breaks points on.</i></p>
                  <span>
                     <h1>DOT NET ARTICLES</h1>
                  </span>

                  <span class="comments"><i>by</i> <a>JOHN WOO</a> <i> - 10 Commments</i></span><br/>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
                  <div class="input-group">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control search-input-box" placeholder="Search..." />
                     <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="hr-style"/>
            <p class = "header-pgf">
               Text, navigation, and tables, oh, my! What's a responsive web designer to do? How can you confine your design to as few major breakpoints as possible? Where and when will you sketching?  Is it possible to sketch on actual devices, and what are the accessibility implications of doing so? The answers to these and other profound questions will be found in this exclusive excerpt from Chapter 7 of Responsive Design Workflow, Stephen Hay's new book, available now from New Riders.
            </p>
            <hr class="hr-style">
            <h1 class="more-apart">More from A List Apart</h1>
            <hr class="hr-style">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h2>Columnists</h2>
                  <p>JACK MCGRANE <i>on</i> CONTENT</p>
                  <p class="pgf-header">The Alternative is Nothing</p>
                  <img src="img/thumb1.jpg" class="float-left" /> 
                  <p>We're witnessing one of thr latest waves of technological disruption, as mobile devices put access to the internet in the hands of people who previously never had that power.</p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h2>From the Blog</h2>
                  <p class="pgf-header">Maps Should Be Crafted.Not "Plugged In"></p>
                  <p>Web designers: erase the line between "the map" and "the content" by harnessing the power of open-source Leafler and your own fresh creative thinking. In the tradition of ALA's recent "Hack Your Maps." Happy Cog's Brandon Rosage shares how to make location a central aspect of the content experience-not just a visual aid.</p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3">
                  <p class="md-3">Amazon Web Services Introduces a New API</p>
                  <p>Amazon Web Services Identity and Access Management(IAM) is expanding to support web identity federation. Developers can integrate Amazon.com, Facebook, or Google odentity into their app by using the new AWS Security Token Services(STS) API, AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity. to request temporary security credentials.</p>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3">
                  <h5>Gratitude</h5>
                  <p>Thanks to our RSS sponser Typekit-offering desktop and web fonts in a single subscription starting June 17</p>
                  <div class="well align-center">
                     <img src="img/mothers-day.jpg" /> <br/>
                     <p class="font-10">Two special Mothers' Say Kits are available from Field Notes Brand. Ad via The Deck </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="job-board">
                     <h5>Job Board</h5>
                     <a href="#" >New York Times is looking for a <br />Ruby on Rails Web Developer.</a>
                     More on the <a href ="#">Job Board ></a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <br />
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /container -->
      <div class="footer" style="">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="list-footer" style="font-size:13px;">
               <span class="padding-10"><img src="img/article-logo.png" /></span>
               <span class="padding-10">ARTICLES</span>
               <span class="padding-10">COLUMNS</span>
               <span class="padding-10">BLOG</span>
               <span class="padding-10">TOPICS</span>
            </div>
            <div class = "list-footer" style="font-size:12px;"> 
               <span class="padding-10">ABOUT</span>
               <span class="padding-10">AUTHORS</span>
               <span class="padding-10">MASTHEAD</span>
               <span class="padding-10">CONTRIBUTE</span>
               <span class="padding-10">STYLE GUIDE</span>
               <span class="padding-10">CONTACT</span>
               <span class="padding-10">SPONSORSHIPS</span>
            </div>
            <hr class="hr-style"/>

            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <img src="img/dot-net-ad.jpg" class="footer-image"/> 
                  <h3>.NET Training</h3>
                  <p class="footer-pgf">If you have a .NET question on a topic that 's not covered by other more specific forums.</p>
                  <a class="footer-link" href="#">ask here. ></a> 
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <img src="img/shopify-expert-ad.jpg" class="footer-image"/> 
                  <h3>Shopify Expert</h3>
                  <p class="footer-pgf">Unique custom made Shopify theme and tweaks.</p>
                  <a class="footer-link" href="#">click to view</a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="hr-style" />
            <div style="text-align:center">
               <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2013 Dot Net How</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It provides support for ARIA (Accessible Rich Internet Applications) which allows to specify even more semantic richness in documents.

> You can add role="search" to your search form, role="banner" to your
>   masthead, and role="contentinfo" to your page footer. There’s a full
>   list of values in the ARIA specification at
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#role_definitions.

Basically you don't have to add them, but its better if you do as it provides more context for your page.  More discussed at [A List Apart.](http://alistapart.com/article/semanticsinhtml5)

Comment: If i remove them, there is no change in my page.

Comment: Yes, you don't have to add them.  They help in in something invisible called the semantic web, which is an idea of providing more meaning to the web apart from just visual changes (albeit there are changes for impaired people though).

Comment: now my question is, i use or not?

Comment: Didn't you read what he just said? It's up to you

Comment: It depends on who your target audience is and if its worth the effort.  Generally I don't really use it unless clients ask since its too time consuming, and if you check most major websites (view source), they don't really have them (afaik).

Answer (score 2):

The new structural elements in HTML5 will be very useful to assistive technology. Instead of creating “skip navigation” links, all we need to do is use the nav element correctly. This will allow screen reader users to skip past navigation without us having to provide an explicit link.

Twitter Bootstrap uses like `<nav role="navigation">`. So Bootstrap take consider not only normal browser but also take care of screen reader browsers.

**Note:** By including `Role` attribute you are making your website more accessible and its good practice to use this `Role` attribute.